# How to serve "/something" and "/something/" both on Golang(go-chi) router?

Tags: go, routes, url-routing, go-chi

I am using go-chi router for my application but I am unable to serve "/something" and "/something/" both with one route, if I set my route as "/something"

```
r := chi.NewRouter()
r.Get("/something", func(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    writer.Write([]byte("just for test"))
})
```

and then request "/something/" its give me *404 page not found* error.Is there any way to serve both case with one route?

Comment: please define _I am unable_, any errors?

Comment: sorry , actually if I set my route as "/something" then request "/something/" url it's give me _404 page not found_

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Where's your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use middleware StripSlashes, that change path "/something/"  to "/something"